# HW requirements for 13.04/13.10

Tags: system-requirements

I'm sorry if this has been asked and addressed already.

What are the HW pre requisites for Ubuntu 13.04/13.10?

I'm a big fan of Ubuntu and wish to install it on my 9 year old PC. Wondering if it will work.

Comment: See [Installation/SystemRequirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) on the [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score -1):

According to:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/preparing-to-install.html
```

these are the minimum hardware requirements for 13.04:

```
    Install Type      CPU        RAM             Hard Drive Space     
                                            Base System     All Tasks Installed

Server (Standard)    1 GHz      512 MB         1 GB               1.75 GB

 Server (Minimal)   300 MHz     128 MB       700 MB               1.4  GB
```